# Deleting the values in Child table first and then Parent table

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement like SCD Type-1. (Insert, Update & Delete)

Source is file.
Target is DB2 Tables (Tbl_1 & Tbl_2 - Both Contains Parent & Child relationship).

Here I used full outer join and flagged rows for Insert, Update & Delete and checked the Constraint based load order.

Now While deleting, I need to delete the Child table first and then Parent table. How can achieve this? Any idea?

Comment: Why not just separate this into two maps?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't delete from a slowly changing dimension, but if you are going to delete, you first have to make sure that the dimension key is not used in any fact tables that reference it.  Therefore once you have identified the source key for the dimension row that is to be deleted, you must perform a lookup using the surrogate key into all the referencing fact tables to make sure that dimension row is not referenced before you can delete it.

The question is then, how do you identify, based on what's in the source file, what needs to be deleted?